# Missing voice input button on the standard keyboard - Lollipop

Tags: gboard

Posting and answering this to help others experiencing the same issue as me. This was also asked [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/482290-5-01-no-voice-input-method-enabled.html).

If only one keyboard is enabled, i.e. Google Keyboard - English (US), the keyboard shown whenever text input is needed sometimes does not have a microphone icon (or any option to select voice typing).

Some things that may not show:

- Microphone icon (in older Android versions, this was beside the space bar on the on-screen keyboard)
- Pressing and holding space bar does not trigger the input selection screen (that normally would have featured voice typing as an option).

Please refer to my own answer below
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104896/198

Answer (score 7):

Try installing the [Google application from the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox).

I disabled the Google App on my phone and the voice commands were gone from the keyboard. When I re-enabled it, the microphone icon was back. Hope that helps.

Comment: This was my issue. When I installed this, the voice typing input method magically appeared.  Thank you!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well, I disabled the "Google Search" app thinking I didn't need it and lost the voice input method along with it. Was scratching my head until I figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions that I found:

1. Microphone icon

   - This has now been moved to the text correction area of the keyboard. **Text correction may not be enabled on your device.** Enable this by heading to Settings -> Language & input -> Google Keyboard -> Text correction -> Enable "Show correction suggestions." This was roughly mentioned [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3601052/how-turn-off-predictive-text-change-keyboard-settings-in-android/).
2. Pressing and holding the space bar

   - I managed to get this option to work by enabling another keyboard in addition to the Google English (US) keyboard and Google voice typing. Like in the previous item, head over to Settings -> Language & input, then go to Current Keyboard. On the popup screen, select "Choose Keyboards" to select another input method such as Google Korean Input. You should now be able to press and hold the space bar during text input to select voice typing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, I had unknowingly turned off "show correction suggestions" somehow and it was driving me crazy trying to get mic icon to show on QWERTY keyboard. 
I had found the workaround of installing a second keyboard (Handwriting) and was able to get to voice typing but very frustrating work around!

Answer (score 3):

Additionally I found under language and input > default there is an "add keyboards" option. In my case "google voice typing" was unchecked for some reason.

Comment: This solution definitely works on Android 4.4.2.  It is the only setting that I needed to change.

Answer (score 3):

While no answer provide's a straight solution, I'd like to add one.

This is for Android 5+

Go to settings > language and input > in "keyboards and input methods" submenu click on the keyboard that is active you should now be in a menu with > preferences, advanced, gesture typing options  > click on preferences > you'll find a "voice input key" option just select/deselect to activate/deactivate

Answer (score 1):

I was able to press and hold on the settings icon [image: settins icon]

and the microphone icon appeared along with settings and email icon. I tapped on it and the mic icon was back on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Lollipop (I tried on 5.1.1), if you enable another language input method editor (IME, for example, Japanese IME or Hindi IME) and also have the Google voice typing enabled in the language and input settings, then when you start typing in any app where you can type, you hold down the spacebar and you will get a small menu showing you the option to voice type, then just tap the option and the voice typing input will open.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: https://i.imgur.com/gDjrW9q.png]

Answer (score 0):

I found it for my LG G4

Settings - General - Language & Input - Keyboard Settings - Keyboard Height & Layout - QWERTY Keyboard Layout